# In Cypher, nodes are queried if they have edges type A. How to display other edge type they have?

Tags: cypher

In my graph the edges have two types: `A` and `B`. I want to query all the nodes having edges type `A`. Within those nodes, if they have edges `B` then they should be displayed as well. So for example, if we have `(node1)-[A]-(node2)`, `(node3)-[A]-(node4)`, and if there are `B` edges between those 4 nodes, then only them should be displayed, not all other `B`s.

I try both:

```sql
match (n)-[r:A]-(m) 
match (n)-[s:B]-(m) 
return n,r,s,m
```

and

```sql
match (n)-[r:A]-(m),
 (n)-[s:B]-(m) 
return n,r,s,m
```

But none of them works.

I don't use Neo4j Browser, so the edges need to be explicitly queried. The manual for [`MATCH`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/) doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, since you seem to be looking for triangles

```
MATCH (n)-[r1:A]-(m)-[r2:A]-(k)
OPTIONAL MATCH (k)-[r3:B]-(n)
```

Comment: Yeah, triangle is a good word. But this seems to limit to triangle only. If n and k don't have B, they should be returned as well, since they still have A

Comment: Use optional. See edited answer

Comment: I use `match (n)-[r:A]-(m) optional match (n)-[s:B]-() return n,m,r,s` and get what I want